# FactoryGirl factory failing due to logic in AR callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, factory-bot

I have a FactoryGirl factory for my `Appointment` model.  Ex:

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :appointment do |f|
    f.name { 'Pending Appointment' }
  end
end
```

The `Appoinment` model has many `AppointmentAccess` instances.  It creates them in an ActiveRecord callback on the `Appointment` model.  The `AppointmentAccess` is a through model, relating the `Appointment` to a `User`.

I added a callback to the Factory (see below), but an error is still being thrown in the `Appointment` model's AR callback due to the AR callback running prior to the FactoryGirl callback:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointment_accesses
  has_many :users, through: :appointment_accesses

  after_create :example_callback

  protected

  def example_callback
    owner = self.appointment_accesses.find_by(owner: 1)

    owner.name
  end
end
```

Since the model's callback is running before the FactoryGirl callback, it's throwing an error because the `AppointmentAccess` with `owner` set to 1 does not yet exist.  Here's my FactoryGirl factory with the callback (same as above, with callback):

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :appointment do |f|
    f.name { 'Pending Appointment' }

    after(:create) do |appointment|
      FactoryGirl.create(:appointment_access, appointment: appointment)
    end
  end
end
```

How can I make sure that before the callback on the `Appointment` model runs, that the FactoryGirl callback runs first (since the ActiveRecord logic requires it)?

Comment: Maybe it will not help you with your problem but try to avoid callbacks

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing a new `AppointmentAccess` record along with the new `Appointment` using the `before(:create)` callback.

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :appointment do |f|
    f.name { 'Pending Appointment' }

    before(:create) do |appointment|
      # initializes a new AppointmentAccess and adds it to the collection
      appointment.appointment_accesses << FactoryGirl.build(:appointment_access)
    end
  end
end
```

When the `Appointment` is actually saved, it will also save the initialized `AppointmentAccess` along with it at which point the `after_create` callback in the model will run.

Comment: This is working, but now I'm getting a Stack Level Too Deep, because the AppointmentAccess creates an Appointment factory.  When I remove it from the AppointmentAccess factory, it doesn't pass validation (appointment is required).  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it makes sense. I'd recommend that you take a look at your data model as issues like these can tend to indicate that you've got some circular dependencies and that you might be able to better organize things. That being said, why don't we either (1) build the `AppointmentAccess` manually, e.g. `appointment.appointment_accesses.build(...)` or (2) try using `FactoryGirl.build(:appointment_access, appointment: nil)` to stop the second factory from calling the first

Comment: Still Stack Level Too Deep.  Validation doesn't pass when I don't set it in AppointmentAccess, but you would think that since it's setting the appointment on the AppointmentAccess in the `before(:create)` that it wouldn't create a new appointment, that was the goal at least, right?

Comment: Yeah I'd have to look deeper into what your factories look like. Your models feel too tightly coupled, and using AR callbacks is frowned upon in certain cases because it creates situations like these.